# How Can I Disable "Pinch Zoom" in Foundation Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Can I disable "Pinch Zoom" in my web application ? How ?

Or that the application locks in responsiveness that it detects when you open the application?
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this in your `<head>` area:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course

```
        /* Prevent elements to be highlighted on tap */
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
         /* Put the scroller into the HW Compositing layer right from the start */
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        -o-text-size-adjust: none;
        text-size-adjust: none;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
```